# Expected value of the sum of n randomly picked integers between 1 and 10.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

The problem is the following, imagine there is a box that is filled with pieces of paper and each of the pieces has an integer between 1 to 10 written on it, the distribtuion of pieces in the bag is uniform. The question is what is the expected value of the sum of the numbers on n randomly picked papers. The hint that is given by the problem is to use indicator random variables.

$X1,...,Xn$  are identically distributed, independent random variables and that each of them is a uniform draw from ${1,...,10}$.

First I have noticed that the expected value of the sum is between $[n,10n]$ which is a simple sanity check to keep in mind when doing operations.

Secondly after trials and errors I am guessing that the PMF of the sum random variable is normally distributed or at least close to being so, and I am expecting the result to be somewhere between $[4n,6n]$

I have tried to open up the expectation $E[X]=\sum_{i=n}^{10n} i*P(X=i)=n*\frac{1}{10^n}+(n+1)*\frac{1}{10^{n-2}}+...+10^n*\frac{1}{10^n}$ but no, I was not able to obtain any meaningful form of this that is possible to work with.

As you can see my mathematical apparatus is not yet sufficient to generate any meaningful results for this problem beyond non-rigorous guesses.

If it is possible please provide the explanation of how it is possible to solve the problem with indicator random variables as I cannot even come up with a single good idea on approaching this.

Also if it is possible please pinpoint any literature or similar problems so I can get familiar with this types of problems and be prepared in the future.

Comment: Are you picking with or without replacement?

Comment: It is not explicitly stated in the problem. But I assume it is with replacement.

Comment: "Each of the pieces has an integer between 1 to 10 written on it" — with what distribution? As written, this means that all of the papers could be $3$, or half of them could be $1$ and the other half evenly distributed among the remaining numbers, etc.

Comment: Where are you getting the normal distribution from???

Comment: I have stated that it is just a non-rigorous and completely unjustified guess. I wrote it to introduce what thinking process I have gone into and  getting to know why it is wrong would be good for me as well.

Comment: Each draw is expected to contribute $5$.  So the answer is $5n$.

Comment: @Théophile I assume the distribution is uniform.  I have not even thought about that before thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is clearer if you say that $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are identically distributed, independent random variables and that each of them is a uniform draw from $\{1, \cdots, 10\}$.  Then you want $E\left[\sum X_i\right]=nE[X_1]=5n$.  The part about the box and pieces of paper is just confusing and potentially misleading.

Comment: @lulu I was given the problem as I wrote. I will take into account the suggestions of all of you and properly edit the problem statement thank you.

Comment: Sure, I understand that.  But as you see from the comments, a big part of the problem is figuring out what the problem is saying.  Of course, I am not sure that my interpretation is correct!  Though I can't see another that makes sense for all $n$.  If $n≤10$ then you can imagine a choice without replacement (though, as it turns out, that doesn't matter).

Comment: Note:  as @copper.hat  correctly demonstrates, I botched the computation of the average of $\{1, 2, \cdots, 10\}$.  Of course, it is $5.5$, not $5$.

Comment: @copper.hat: would that make a difference ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which, the distribution?

Comment: @copper.hat: replacement.

Comment: @jsbc Yes, presumably whoever made the problem intended for the distribution to be uniform. Details matter! As a thought experiment, imagine this game: I'm holding a secret prize behind my back, and it's worth anywhere from \$0 to \$1,000,000. You'll flip a coin, and if you win, you get the prize. Would you be willing to pay me half a million dollars to play the game? :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust No difference for $n \le 10$ but undefined subsequently. However the computation is not as simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_k $ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,...,10\}$ then
$E[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k] = \sum_{k=1}^n E X_k = n EX_1 = n {11 \over 2}$.

Comment: I got a bit confused by the notation of your random Variable $X$. I thought it maps the sum of all numbers on n randomly picked papers to the corresponding probabilities. Can you please give a more formal defnition of $X_k$. Thank you.

Comment: $P[X_k = i] = {1 \over 10}$ for $i=1,...,10$.

Comment: Thank you now I see. The problem seemed much more complex than before. It is wonderful how much mathematics can change ones perception